# Using direct comparison on $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^2 - 1} dx.$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I have $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{2} - 1}dx$. I did not initially recognize the vertical asymptote and just compared with $\frac{1}{x^{2}}$. Can I do this, or do I need to split the integral?

Comment: No you can't just do that because that would be glossing over the problem at $x=1$

Comment: The question posed isn't clear. Are you trying to prove the integral is convergent as it approaches infinity? Or are you trying to prove it is convergent at $x = 1$? What is the original problem?

Comment: Save your efforts. Your integral is divergent as you can simply observe, if you try to evaluate $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_{0}^{1-\epsilon}(x^2-1)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary to pay some attention to what's really going on. We define the improper integral
$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^2 - 1} dx = \lim_{a \to 1} \int_0^a \frac{1}{x^2 - 1} dx + \lim_{\substack{b \to 1 \\ c \to \infty}} \int_b^c \frac{1}{x^2 - 1} dx.$$
From only first principles, it would be inappropriate to compare to the integral of $1/x^2$ on the infinite half-line $[0, \infty)$.

Further, it is not always true that $\frac{1}{x^2} < \frac{1}{x^2 - 1}$ (incorrect at, for example, $1/2$), so it would not be possible to directly compare the two functions over the whole interval anyway.